# How can I add a "Send copy of email to self" checkbox in Contact Form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to use the following, but I cannot get this code to work.

```
function check_mail_send_contactform($cf7) {
    //get CF7's mail and posted_data objects
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }
    $mail = $cf7->prop( 'mail' );

    if($posted_data['contact_sendmail'][0]) { //if Checkbox checked
        $mail2 = $cf7->prop( 'mail_2' ); //get CF7's mail_2 object
        //now set sender's address to mail2's recipient
        $mail2['recipient'] = $mail['sender'];
        $mail2['active'] = true;
        $cf7->set_properties( array( 'mail_2' => $mail2 ) );
    }
    return $cf7;
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','check_mail_send_contactform');
```

I've dumped mail_2 and it seems to be setup correctly; active, recipient set and email message setup w headers, etc.